# How to send email using smtp in zf2?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, smtp

I make a zf2 action in which i want to send email to user that saved in database so i used gmail for sending emails but email not sent to user.

How i send email in zf2?

Here is my code:

```
public function addAction()
{
    //check permissions
    if(!$this->acl->isAllowed($this->user->user_type, 'user.create'))
    $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin_index');
    //
    $this->layout()->top_heading = 'Add User';      
    $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');
    ////////////////////////////////
    $form = new UserForm();
    $update=false;
    $message='';
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $form->setInputFilter($form->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($post);
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $formData=$form->getData();
            $s = new User();
            $user = $dm->getRepository('Calendar\Document\User')->findOneBy(array(
                "username" => $formData['username']
            ));
            $email = $dm->getRepository('Calendar\Document\User')->findOneBy(array(
                "email" => $formData['email']
            ));
            if($user || $email)
            {
                $update=2;
                $message='User Already Exists.';    
            }
            if($post['role']=='admin')
            {
                $update=2;
                $message="Select Some Other Role."; 
            }
            else
            {
                $s->setProperty('username',$post['username']);
                $s->setProperty('password',md5($post['password']));
                $s->setProperty('email',$post['email']);
                $s->setProperty('user_type',$post['role']);
                $s->setProperty('dataentered',date('Y-m-d H:m:i'));
                $dm->persist($s);
                $dm->flush();
                //echo new Response($s->getProperty('id'));
                //
                $update=1;
                $message='User Added Successfully.';
                $form = new UserForm();
                $config = array('ssl' => 'tls',
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'marif252@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'password');

                $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
                $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                $mail->setBodyHtml($bodytext);
                $mail->setFrom('marif252@gmail.com');
                $mail->addTo($formData['email'], $formData['username']);
                $mail->setSubject('Profile Activation');
                $mail->send($transport);
```

How to send email using gmail in zf2?

Comment: See this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mail.transport.html

Comment: I used this but no email sent

Comment: Is the e-mail simply not in your inbox or do you get an error message? Did you check your spam folder? did you check your php_error.log as well?

Comment: i checked my error log this error show Fatal error:  Class 'Calendar\\Controller\\Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp' not found in

Comment: @MuhammadArif Your code is *still* using unsanitized post data. Anything using `$post['foo']` is from the request instance and is just raw post data - You **need** to use `$formData['foo']` when setting the entity properties as this would be the *validated* data via the `InputFilter`.

Comment: @MuhammadArif how did you solve this issue..? You accepted the answer, did this work..I am also getting Could not open socket error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using smtp like this:

```
$message = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
$message->setBody('This is the body');
$message->setFrom('myemail@mydomain.com');
$message->addTo('someone@somedomain.com');
$message->setSubject('Test subject');

$smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();  
$smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
            ->setConnectionClass('login')
            ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
            ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                'username' => 'YOUR GMAIL ADDRESS',
                'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD',
                'ssl' => 'tls',
            ));

$transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
$transport->send($message);
```

Comment: but where i set $post[email]?

Comment: i use your code but error message shown Could not open socket

Comment: Does your server support openssl? Make sure extension=php_openssl.dll is uncommented in php.ini ..if it is then try to comment 'ssl'=>'tls'

Comment: i checked my openssl is enabled so i comment 'ssl'=>'tls' but same error exist

Comment: Can you check error logs? If you could not - then pls call your hosting company and tell them about this error

Comment: I used the same code and work perfect on my local system but when I move the code to my godaddy, It says connection refuse for smtp, Can you please get the solution for the this.

Comment: You need to check with hosting provider - many times it turned out that their firewall settings block some ports.